# Loading angularjs controller dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a form and on button click partial cshtml is loaded dynamically.I want to add Angularjs validations for the dynamic content but the dynamic content is loaded out of angular scope and  none of the angular properties are working with it...So how can i bind the dynamic content with the existing form that has the angular properties.

Please help me with some suggestions...

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly: Make sure the dynamic content is loaded inside the domain of the controller doing validation (eg on form fields inside the controller's div), and run $scope.$apply() after the content loads into this context. Assuming your validation procedure is complete this should re-run validation.